# How do I run a SQL query to extract a specific product range?

Tags: magento-enterprise, database, mysql, sql

I got a probably really simple question but I couldn´t find a solution for now. I found heaps of questions etc. but for now nothing which would be what I need.

I am trying to use a query on magento but I´m wondering how I run the SQL command.

I want to run something like

```
select substr(sku,1) as sku 
.....and so on....
```

and then I want the result to be written in a .txt file

**UPDATE**

I want to run the following command

```
select substr(sku,1) as sku 
  from catalog_product_entity
  where sku like 'S%'
  order by sku asc;
```

and then write that in a .csv or .txt file. Where does the code go and where will the file be? I need a full explanation if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SUBSTRING` returns a `specified number of characters from a particular position of a given string`.

In magento,you can use the function `getSubstringSql($stringExpression, $pos)`.It is PDO library function. By which you can create `sub string of a field`.

**$stringExpression** may be a  field name or SQL

```
   public function getSubstringSql($stringExpression, $pos, $len = null)
    {
        if (is_null($len)) {
            return new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUBSTRING(%s, %s)', $stringExpression, $pos));
        }
        return new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUBSTRING(%s, %s, %s)', $stringExpression, $pos, $len));
    }
```

**Example:**

```
$Collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$Collection
    ->getSelect()
    ->getSubstringSql('name',10);
```

**You can try this**

```
$Collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
$Collection
    ->getSelect()
    ->getSubstringSql('sku',1)
```

**Update**:
According to your chat you need use like in condition

```
$Collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('sku')->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array(
   'like' => 'A%',

));
```

### According your update

I have add new columns to using zend expression

```
$productCollection=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('sku')->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array(
   'like' => 'A%'));

 $productCollection->getSelect();   
$write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");
$requestPathField = new Zend_Db_Expr($write->quoteIdentifier('sku'));
 $write->getSubstringSql($requestPathField,1);

echo $productCollection->getSelect()->columns(array('mysku' =>  $write->getSubstringSql($requestPathField,1)));
foreach($productCollection as $product):
echo $product->getMysku().'<br/>';
endforeach;
```

See at http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

Comment: Thanks for that quick response, but can I not run a normal SQL command somehow on my Magento database?

Comment: Yes.you can do this and it is ok whenever want to only fetch sku fields.Please explain what is your requirement

Comment: I want to get a list from all the products where the SKU starts with a specific letter

So I thought I can do Substr(sku,1) as Sku
from xxxx
where sku like 'A%';

But where do I run this so that I will get a file at the end containing all the products?

Comment: Amit I updated my description can you help me again.

Comment: please  check  my update ....

Comment: okay now finally my last question, where do I put to code and how to run it to at the end get a csv file?

Comment: Thomas,You updated the question again and again.......it change the answer type several times.So  i am requesting to you create another  new question basic of this question with referral link.I will give the answer of that quetsion.And Please accept above answer